# ES6/AngularJs 1.5.5 directive/ngMessages Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6, angularjs-components

I am using angular.js 1.5.5 and ES6

My project uses gulp, webpack (I am mentioning this as I am not sure if this is causing any troubles around some exclusion/inclusion of angular-message.js in the final files that are included in my SPA's final index.html)

Here is the definition of the component/directive that sits in a file: 
$project_home/client/components/account-info/index.js Following code is what throws the error when I visit the page that has this directive.

```
'use strict';

import angular from 'angular';
import ngMessages from 'angular-messages';

import AccountInfoController from './account-info.controller';
import UserService from '../../../auth/user.service';

export default angular
  .module('directives.accountInfoForm', [ngMessages])
  .service('UserService', UserService)
  .component('accountInfoForm', {
    template: require('./account.html'),
    controller: AccountInfoController,
    bindings: {
      user: '<',
      onUpdate: '&'
    }
  })
  .name;
```

If I remove ngMessages from line `.module('directives.accountInfoForm', [ngMessages])` then I don't see this error message but of course the ngMessages directive doesn't work either.

Here is the code from the template:

```
<form name="accountForm">
    <div layout-gt-xs="row">
      <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-xs="100" flex="40">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="$ctrl.user.email" required="required" name="emailAddress">
        <div
          ng-if="acccountForm.emailAddress.$touched"
          ng-messages="accountForm.emailAddress.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">Email is required.</div>
          <div ng-message="email">Enter a valid email.</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

...and here is how I am using this directive:

```
<account-info-form user="$ctrl.user" on-update="$ctrl.createAccount($event)"></account-info-form>
```

Is this issue because I am not specifying the right way for ngMessages in ES6 syntax or something completely different issue altogether? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with require: { } in the component declaration. Still not success though. :-(

Comment: Alright, figured it out myself. Nothing do with component/directives. All I was doing wrong was:using old version of angular-messages (I am using 1.5.9 instead of 1.5.3)

Comment: ..and my template had one orphaned <ng-message> element without being nested in the <ng-messages> element - this was the main reason for issue that I faced.